# Measuring Lumberjacks

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

On average, a lumberjack is 10 logs taller (logs are usually measured in feet) than a normal person plus the height of his tan. Remember that most lumberjacks are young Canadians. Fill the blanks of the following heights and explain why my reasoning is valid. Resulting heights are to be rounded to the closest whole number.

> Before:
>   65", 66", 69", 71", 83", 89".
>
> After Lumberjackification Ritual:
>   201, 204, 212, ?  , ?  , 402.

---

Hints:

1. A lumberjack's tan, or sunburn, is a 1st *degree* burn.

---

- This information is mostly (completely) false in real life.
- All information provided was given for a reason. Do not edit out the (made up) Canadian part.

Comment: is 121 meant to be 221?

Comment: Not quite. 121 was wrong but has been fixed (212). Sorry guys, it was late when I posted. Looking forward to the solutions, best of luck all. :D

Comment: Hint: $log = \log(x)$, $tan = \tan(y)$, $\mbox{something + log(x)}$, $\mbox{something + tan(y)}$.

Comment: The hint given as an answer was rather ovious, but I can't figure out why they have to be Canadians. Perhaps Canadians rhymes with radians?

Comment: In the 1970's something happened to Canada. Getting to add 'young' was just a further hint as to what I was referring to... What happened in the 1970's to Canada that affects my results?

Comment: @GuillaumeL. The thing I did was y= math on x, why give y a tan?

Comment: I believe the "young Canadian" comment probably has something to do with the metrication of Canada.

Comment: Ok... I have been juggling numbers all evening. My Idea is that Canadian refers to the Metric system. So my formula would be `newheight = heigth + log(height)*10 + tan(height)` and convert the height from inch to centimeter, but I just can't get the numbers to match up :-/ I also tried changing the interpretation of the tan() parameter to degrees and radians...

Comment: @Falco I understand your frustration.Try 10 log(s)(or ed?), not referring to height at all but instead adding a constant value of 10 logs.

Comment: I have been guiding people in the correct direction due to the difficulty and potential for misinterpretation. (I will still try to word my answers strangely as to give nothing away) Puzzles aren't fun when you give up!

Comment: I'm with Falco. Worked on it for a while and came up with numbers that are close but don't quite match up with those given.

Comment: log(height) wont work and doesn't fit my wording. try replacing it with log(10). Also remember the unit of that result is anonymous *cough*ft. *cough*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I finally got it... a really nice riddle, except the part with 10 logs measuring in feet...

> So 10 logs taller is log(10) in feet, so 1 foot or 12 inches 
>  The tan of a lumberjack is the tangens-function of his height (taken as degrees) 
>  The result has to be converted from inch to cm (factor 2.54) 
>  because Canadians
>  changed to the metric system!

The formula for lumberfication of old height h is:

> (h + tan(h) + 12) * 2.54

This matches all numbers and results in:

> (71 + tan(71°) + 12) * 2.54 = 218
>  
>  (83 + tan(83°) + 12) * 2.54 = 262

Comment: Correct, nice job! I will admit that the 12 inches instead of 1 inch thing was a afterthought of my first riddle (at first I was working in feet) that goes against the mindset that the puzzler has developed over time (in.). So for that, I would like to apologise. I will try to do a better job of designing for the player and not the riddle next time. Glad you enjoyed the riddle.

Comment: @user3155415 I really enjoyed the riddle, everything else was a nice Idea, especially the tan ;-) I proposed an edit to the question, which would make the riddle consistently great :-)

Comment: nice edit, originally I was just doing logs but then I brainstormed on punny math abbreviations about lumberjacks and figured they had tans.

Comment: The mistake in my logic was trying to take 10log(x) where x is the height...

Comment: One could edit the question and add (...always 10 logs taller, irrsepective of his height...) but it is solvable ;-)